# How to get fixed effects in an FE model in R

Tags: r, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

In an equation as such:

$$log(P_{is})=B_0+B_1log(X1_{is})+B_2log(X2_{is})+B_3X3_{is}+e_i$$

for firms $i$ across $25$ periods from $s=1$ to $s=25$ (panel data).

The output in R for fixed effects only gives me estimates for $X1$, $X2$, and $X3$ (all time-varying variables naturally). How do I get the fixed effects?

As mentioned before, the summary for the **fixed** command only gives me estimates for $X1$, $X2$, and $X3$. The summary of **fd**, which is *Oneway (individual) effect First-Difference Model*, gives me an intercept. I also get an intercept for **between** (that is *Oneway (individual) effect Between Model* in plm). What else can I try if none of these are the fixed effect I am looking for?

Comment: Have you tried to use the function `fixef` form the package **plm**?

Comment: Please show your summary of ouput.

Comment: Whoud  you like to explain your problem for research and hypotheses/objectives ?

Comment: @mpiktas Thanks a lot - that was it! `fixef(fixed)` gives the fixed effects. Cheers

Comment: @mpiktas the `fixef` command gives me **only** estimates, though (no p values or anything). Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

In `lfe`, the function is `getfe()`.

More generally, reformulate your equation into groupwise means, then do a bit of rearranging to isolate the Fe term.